# li element hover event and show sub menu?

Tags: jquery, html, menu, submenu

html codes

```
<ul class="menu">
<li>deneme</li>
<li>deneme
    <ul>
        <li>alt menu</li>
        <li>alt menu</li>
        <li>alt menu</li>
        <li>alt menu</li>
        <li>alt menu</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>deneme
    <ul>
        <li>alt menu</li>
        <li>alt menu</li>
        <li>alt menu</li>
        <li>alt menu</li>
        <li>alt menu</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>deneme</li>
<li>deneme</li>
<li>deneme
    <ul>
        <li>alt menu</li>
        <li>alt menu</li>
        <li>alt menu</li>
        <li>alt menu</li>
        <li>alt menu</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>deneme</li>
</ul>​
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul.menu > li").css("color","red");
    $("li ul li").css("color","blue")
    $("li ul li").hide();
    $("ul.menu li").hover(
        function() {
            $("li ul li").show();
        },
        function() {
            $("li ul li").hide();
        }
    );
});​
```

And my question, I want to show current's submenu item with hover event. But this code show all sub menus. How can I fix it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Fix your selector to only fetch `this`'s sub list items.

Comment: I cant find correct selector syntax.

Comment: 1. Always include the relevant code and markup **in the question itself**, don't just link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question 2. Show some basic respect for the community by reading your question over and fixing the worst of the typos before posting.

Comment: sorry I editted it. Thanks your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide a context for the element selection in the hover handler.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("ul.menu > li").css("color", "red");
    $("li ul li").css("color", "blue")
    $("li ul li").hide();
    $("ul.menu li").hover(

    function() {
        $("ul li", this).show();
    }, function() {
        $("ul li", this).hide();
    }

    );

});​
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/eygsY/22/

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/eygsY/24/

Provide context for your selector (Only search below `this`, not the whole document):

```
function() {
    $("ul li", this).show();
}, function() {
    $("ul li", this).hide();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should take `this` in the hover which will be your `LI` that the user is hovering over, and find the `li`s inside of it and show those.  Like the following ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3vsQt/1/)):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("ul.menu > li").css("color","red");
  $("li ul li").css("color","blue")
  $("li ul li").hide();
  $("ul.menu li").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).find("li").show();
    },
    function() {
        $(this).find("li").hide();
    }
  );
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that can help you

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

$("ul.menu > li").css("color","red");
 $("li ul li").css("color","blue")
$("li ul li").hide();
$("ul.menu li").hover(
    function() {
    $(this).find("li").slideDown('slow');
    },
    function() {
    $(this).find("li").slideUp('slow');
    }

);

});​
```

Comment: this is better than others. Thanks